# $\mathbb{P}(A[Y] \mid Y=y)$ vs $\mathbb{P}(A[y])$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

This might be a silly question, but I recently was confused by some notation regarding conditional probabilities. Suppose for any $y$ (for the sake of simplicity say this is a natural number) we are given an (non-deterministic) event $A[y]$. Now lets look at a random variable $Y$ (say $\sim\operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda >0$). Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(A[Y] \mid Y=y) = \mathbb{P}(A[y])?
\end{equation}

Heuristically this seems to be true, since the left hand side is the probability that "$A[Y]$ occurs under the condition, that "$Y=y$", which is also the quantity on the right, right?

I see people using this kind of notation when applying the total law of probability, like this
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(A[Y]) = \sum_{y\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(A[y])\cdot\mathbb{P}(Y=y),
\end{equation}
which confuses me, since, rigorously, there should be a conditional probability here.

Can someone provide a proof/counterexample?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(A[Y] \mid Y=y) = \mathbb{P}(A[y])$ looks to like some kind of definition or explanation of notation

Comment: But both quantities can be well-defined without one being just another notation for the other. So I don't think, that the question of equality is obsolete. Can you elaborate on your comment on why this should just be notation?

Comment: Consider $A[y]=\{ Y = y+1\}$, you'd have $A[Y]=\emptyset$. For your equality to hold you would need the events $A[y]$ and $\{Y=y\}$ to be independent.

Comment: Via Definition $\mathbb{P}(A[Y]|Y=y)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A[Y]\cap Y=y)}{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A[y])}{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)}\overset{!}{=}\mathbb{P}(A[y])$, where  for the second equality we used independence. What is the argument for $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=1$?